# How can I check how much of a path exists in python

Tags: python, path, directory

Let's say on my filesystem the following directory exists:

```
/foo/bar/
```

In my python code I have the following path:

```
/foo/bar/baz/quix/
```

How can I tell that only the `/foo/bar/` part of the path exists?

I can walk the path recursively and check it step by step, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Why do you want to know up to what path exists? If it is for logging purposes, saying the full path does not exist suffices.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam I want to keep track of the directories my code creates so I can restore state afterwards. So if `foo/` exists, but I create the path `foo/bar/baz` I then want to be able to revert back to only having `foo/` exist.

Comment: Then you should keep the restoration point while creating the directory, like this diectory is created, rather than finding out the directory structure that is existing previously. That would be cleaner. Like if you create bar directory under /foo, it would be good to keep track that /foo/bar created, instead of keeping track that /foo is already existing. Am I missing something in your use case?

Comment: well, unfortunately `os.makedirs` doesn't tell me what directories it created, so I have to figure that out by myself.

Comment: os.makedirs should be used only on a controlled environment. Like you need to generate a directory structure under an existing virtualenv which is definitely absent. In all other cases, the best practice is to use makedir. Even though makedirs reduce the code written and looks appealing, if you are touching different paths or not sure of existing path, the best way is to use makedir to create one directory at a time for restoring purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No easy function in the standard lib but not really a difficult one to make yourself.

Here's a function that takes a path and returns only the path that does exist.

```
In [129]: def exists(path):
     ...:     if os.path.exists(path): return path
     ...:     return exists(os.path.split(path)[0])
     ...:

In [130]: exists("/home/sevanteri/src/mutta/oisko/siellä/jotain/mitä/ei ole/")
Out[130]: '/home/sevanteri/src'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple `while` loop with `os.path.dirname()` will suffice the requirement

```
path_string = '/home/moin/Desktop/my/dummy/path'
while path_string:
    if not os.path.exists(path_string):
        path_string = os.path.dirname(path_string)
    else:
        break
# path_string = '/home/moin/Desktop'  # which is valid path in my system
```

Comment: Not really a good idea to check the path for every character in the string. Might even end up with a incorrect result. Let's say there's "Desktop" and "Desk" in the home folder. You'd end up with `"/home/moin/Desk"` with your script.

Comment: @Sevanteri : Well that is not what my code is doing. It will check on per folder basis, not the character. For Example: if `path_string
'/home/moin/Desktop'` then `os.path.split(path_string)` will return tuple
of `('/home/moin', 'Desktop')`. I think you got confused of this `tuple` part with iteration for each char

Comment: @downvoter: Please also mention the reason for down vote?? I hate this anonymous part

Comment: Instead of the os.path.split and take the [0], it would be better to use os.path.dirname. dirname is there just to just do this function.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam: Yes, you are right. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually get your requirements as whether you want every path to be checked or upto some specific level.But for simple sanity checks you can just iterate through the full path create the paths and check the sanity.

```
for i in filter(lambda s: s, sample_path.split('/')):
  _path = os.path.join(_path, i)
   if os.path.exists(_path):
      print "correct path"
```

Comment: I want a function that returns the part of the path that already exists, so I can keep track of what directories I've created. Yes, I know I can do something similar to what your code does, but I was wondering if there is a function that can do something like that already.

Comment: @Sevanteri thanks for that didn't know about the `os.sep` .

Comment: Aaaand I already deleted the comment... When working with paths you should split with os.sep instead.

Comment: And you can replace the lambda function with just `None` and it'll also filter out the falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the only way is to work recursively... Though, I would work up the directory tree. The code isn't too hard to implement:

```
import os

def doesItExist(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        doesItExist(os.path.dirname(directory)
    else:
        print "Found: " + directory
        return directory
```

Comment: You can iterate too, if you start from the root instead of checking the entire path :)